# dnsmasq not available from network namespace at first

Tags: ubuntu, dnsmasq, network-namespaces

ubuntu 16.04, dnsmasq 2.75

NOTE: I have dnsmasq running with `--hostsdir` option so dnsmasq should pick up host entries written to that directory.

Steps to reproduce:

```
... fresh machine boot ...
$> echo 'MY-IP test.domain.com' > $DNSMASQ_HOSTS_DIR/test
$> sudo ip netns add test
$> sudo ip link add veth-test type veth peer name test-eth0
$> sudo ip link set test-eth0 netns test
$> sudo ip addr add 10.0.4.1/24 dev veth-test
$> sudo ip link set veth-test up
$> sudo ip netns exec "test" ip addr add "10.0.4.2/24" dev "test-eth0"
$> sudo ip netns exec "test" ip link set test-eth0 up
$> sudo ip netns exec "test" ip link set lo up
$> sudo ip netns exec "test" ip route add default via "10.0.4.1"
$> sudo ip route add "10.0.4.2/32" via default dev "veth-test"
$> sudo mkdir -p /etc/netns/test
$> sudo bash -c "cat > /etc/netns/test/resolv.conf" << EOL
    nameserver MY_IP
    EOL
$> sudo ip netns exec test bash
test-ns$> host test.domain.com
    ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

So, I've created the network namespace but cannot access my dns server. The following 2 steps fix the problem and result in my confusion.

```
... return to the default global namespace ...
$> sudo service dnsmasq restart
$> sudo ip netns exec test bash
test-ns~# host test.domain.com
    test.domain.com has address MY_IP
    ... WORKS! WHAT?!
```

To my understanding, restarting dnsmasq should not have an effect on the networking of my network namespace. Before the restart I cannot reach the dns server, after the restart (and a new instance of the network namespace shell) I am able to access and get answers from dnsmasq. I cannot understand why dns is not working without the dnsmasq restart, and why it does work afterwards (although I have a feeling they are related :=]).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forcing a tcp dns query works and causes future (non tcp) dns requests to work. So `$> host -T test.domain.com` gets the right response and corrects dns lookups for all network namespaces moving forwards. This is more of a workaround than an "answer" to the question (since I still have no idea why) so posting as a comment.