# dnsmasq running in namespace can't take queries from within namespace

Tags: linux, dnsmasq, network-namespaces, dig

I've set up a default `dnsmasq.conf` with essentially no modifications except:

```
listen-address=192.168.42.2
interface=veth1 # Also tried without
server=8.8.8.8
```

And my `/etc/hosts` looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1    test.testing.com
```

I've then created a namespace like so:

```
# ip netns add spacename
# ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1
# ip link set veth1 netns spacename
# ip addr add 192.168.42.1/24 dev veth0
# ip link set dev veth0 up
# ip netns exec spacename ip addr add 192.168.42.2/24 dev veth1
# ip netns exec spacename ip link set dev veth1 up
# ip netns exec spacename ip route add default via 192.168.42.1
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.42.0/24 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# ip netns exec spacename /bin/bash
(namespace)# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

This all sets up everything nice and dandy.
I can confirm it via:

```
[root@arch Torxed]# ip netns list
spacename (id: 0)
```

### Here's where things get weird

I create a permanent shell inside the namespace and I start dnsmasq.

```
# ip netns spacename /bin/bash
(namespace)# /usr/bin/dnsmasq -k --enable-dbus --user=dnsmasq --pid-file --log-queries --no-daemon
```

And it starts fine. I verify this by issuing:

```
(namespace)# ss -lun
State                Recv-Q                Send-Q                                Local Address:Port                                 Peer Address:Port                
UNCONN               0                     0                                           0.0.0.0:53                                        0.0.0.0:*                   
UNCONN               0                     0                                              [::]:53                                           [::]:*
```

And from the "outside", there's no port listening. As intended. But whenever I do:

```
(namespace)# dig test.testing.com @192.168.42.2
```

Nothing happens. But when I do

```
# dig test.testing.com @192.168.42.2
;test.testing.com.               IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
test.testing.com.        0       IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.42.2#53(192.168.42.2)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 24 19:58:37 CET 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 60
```

It works.. from outside the namespace.
Why on internets green earth **can't I dig from inside the namespace where dnsmasq is running**?

I've double-checked iptables, it has nothing fishy either inside or outside the namespace:

```
[root@arch Torxed]# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

It looks the same inside the namespace.
I can't ping my namespace ip either:

```
(namespace)# ping 192.168.42.2 -c 1
PING 192.168.42.2 (192.168.42.2) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.42.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Pinging the otherside of the namespace works tho, the receiver in the "default domain":

```
(namespace)# ping 192.168.42.1 -c 1
PING 192.168.42.1 (192.168.42.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.42.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.024 ms

--- 192.168.42.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
```

Meaning the namespace can't ping it's own namespace interface IP.

Tried `tcpdump -vv -n -i veth1` from inside the namespace as well. It gives me nothing when I try to ping the ip assigned to `veth1`. But when I ping `veth0` (192.168.42.1) I get the packets without any issues.

I've checked:

- [Dnsmasq problem with Linux network namespace](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/238633/dnsmasq-problem-with-linux-network-namespace)
- [dnsmasq not available from network namespace at first](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366703/dnsmasq-not-available-from-network-namespace-at-first)

None of which really explain why this is or how to solve it.

### Checklist

- No other form of bridging
- iptables: `ACCEPT   all -- anywhere anywhere`  on all tables, chains and policies. No DROP rules what so ever.
- No other firewall installed or active
- All interfaces are up (double checked)
- There's routes to and from the namespace (routing table looks fine)
- Pinging **outside** -> **inside** address works
- Pinging **inside** -> **outside** address works
- Pinging **inside** -> **inside** does **not** work.
- Pinging **outside** -> **outside** works

Where have I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is so silly once you see it.
Everything was correct, except for the fact that the namespace `loopback` device was down.

And since everything locally gets routed through `lo`, that interface has to be up too.

```
# ip netns spacename ip link set up dev lo
# ip netns spacename ip addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
```

Solves the problem. Big thanks to `TJ-` at irc.freenoce.net/#ubuntu

```
00:51 < TJ-> DoXiD: "ip netns spacename ip link set up dev lo"  :D --- it was down!
00:52 < TJ-> DoXiD: I knew it had something to do with the way localhost is handled, but I didn't look at the basics
00:53 < TJ-> DoXiD: anything routed inside the host uses lo
```